# Create pandas DataFrame using unique labels sourced from filenames

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to use it to create a dataset for a convolutional neural network. What I want to achieve is a DataFrame where each column represents the label of the data item.

Firstly I find all the data items and read in their respective paths into two dicts:

```
video_path='/home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mod'

all_videos_path = []
all_videos = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(video_path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".avi"):
            all_videos.append(os.path.join(root, file))
            all_videos_path.append(root)
```

So the `all_videos_path` output is like this:

```
['/home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mod/GolfSwing/Golf-Swing-Side/004',
'/home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mod/GolfSwing/Golf-Swing-Side/001',
'/home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mod/GolfSwing/Golf-Swing-Side/003',
'/home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mod/Lifting/004',
'/home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mod/Lifting/001']
```

I then find the labels for the data items using:

```
all_labels = map(lambda x: x.split('/')[8], all_videos_path)
```

Then I find the unique labels using:

```
unique_labels = np.unique(all_labels)
```

Output:

```
array(['GolfSwing','Lifting'], 
  dtype='|S13')
```

Then I create a Series of the unique labels using:

```
label_dict = pd.Series(range(len(unique_labels)), index=unique_labels)
```

Output:

```
GolfSwing        0
Lifting          1
dtype: int64
```

So now I would like to create a DataFrame which has the unique labels as the column headers with all the data items sorted into their respective columns. As you can see some of the categories have different numbers of data so there would need to be different rows for each column. I've been trying to create a DataFrame but with no luck. Is this actually achievable in pandas and if so how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want to pivoting dataframe by [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html). But with different row is problem - you get `NaN` values:

```
import pandas as pd

all_videos_path = ['/home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mod/GolfSwing/Golf-Swing-Side/004',
'/home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mod/GolfSwing/Golf-Swing-Side/001',
'/home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mod/GolfSwing/Golf-Swing-Side/003',
'/home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mod/Lifting/004',
'/home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mod/Lifting/001']

#create dataframe with list all_videos_path
df =  pd.DataFrame({'links': all_videos_path})
#create new column with labels
df['labels'] = df['links'].str.split('/').str[7]
print df
                                               links     labels
0  /home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mo...  GolfSwing
1  /home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mo...  GolfSwing
2  /home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mo...  GolfSwing
3  /home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mo...    Lifting
4  /home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mo...    Lifting

#
df = df.pivot(index='links', columns='labels', values='labels').reset_index()
print df
labels                                              links  GolfSwing  Lifting
0       /home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mo...  GolfSwing      NaN
1       /home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mo...  GolfSwing      NaN
2       /home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mo...  GolfSwing      NaN
3       /home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mo...        NaN  Lifting
4       /home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mo...        NaN  Lifting

df.loc[df['GolfSwing'].notnull() , 'GolfSwing'] = df['links']
df.loc[df['Lifting'].notnull() , 'Lifting'] = df['links']
del df['links']
```

```
print df
labels                                          GolfSwing  \
0       /home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mo...   
1       /home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mo...   
2       /home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mo...   
3                                                     NaN   
4                                                     NaN   

labels                                            Lifting  
0                                                     NaN  
1                                                     NaN  
2                                                     NaN  
3       /home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mo...  
4       /home/richard/Documents/datasets/ucf_sports/mo...
```